# Как использовать явный курсор с FETCH в цикле и вне его?

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor

Есть вопрос, в котором я бы хотел лучше разобраться.

Когда мы создаем курсор и в `BEGIN` начитаем его выполнять:

```
begin
    open c_cursor;
    fetch c_cursor into r_cursor;
    loop 
    ......
    end loop;
end;
```

Когда я использую `FETCH` вне цикла, оно только 1 раз записывает в `r_cursor` и дальше в цикле я буду работать только с этой одной записью?

А если буду его использовать в цикле, тогда оно будет каждую строчку с курсора записывать в запись, и буду  каждой итерации работать с новой строкой. Правильно ли понимаю?

Comment: *Правильно я понимаю ?* Нет. Когда используется FETCH, значение полей в текущей записи  копируется в переменные, и указатель передвигается на следующую запись. Дальше ты работаешь со значениями, скопированными в переменную (изменишь значение в переменной - всё, потерял). И неважно, где выполняется FETCH - в цикле, вне цикла...

Comment: @Akina Ага, (хочу убедиться правильно ли я понял) то есть неважно в цикле FETCH или вне цикла (если допустим в курсоре 10 записей, то оно тоже будет записывать в RECORD те же 10 записей). А в цикле я только уже обрабатывают, что я хочу вывести в работе с этими 10 записями.  
Извините есть глупый вопрос.

Comment: При открытии курсора выполняется запрос, и все его результаты сохраняются где-то внутри, недоступно для пользователя. По команде FETCH из этого недоступного места выдаётся копия текущей записи в указанные переменные, и там, унутре, указатель текущей записи сдвигается. Всё.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ниже простейший пример для понимания работы с явным крсором, когда в цикле, а когда вне его.

- в #1 идёт обработка *одной записи* считаной в FETCH в цикле
- в #2 идёт считвание *всех записей* в `FETCH` с последующей обработкой записей в цикле

С явным курсором можно считать одну запись вне цикла, но так делать не стоит, для этого существуют неявные курсоры, работать с которыми проще и смысл объявления явного курсора теряется.

```
declare 
    cursor cur is
        select 'row '||rownum id 
        from dual connect by level<=9;
    rec cur%rowtype; 
    type rectab is table of cur%rowtype;
    recs rectab;
begin
    --#1 
    open cur;
    loop 
        fetch cur into rec;
        exit when cur%notfound;
        -- processing data of one rec 
    end loop;
    close cur;
    --#2 
    open cur; 
    fetch cur bulk collect into recs;
    close cur;
    for i in 1..recs.count loop 
        null; -- processing data of one element of recs
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Comment: Нет, я понял. Спасибо

Comment: Извиняюсь, я просто задумался

Comment: @JuniorLittle Бывает, ничего страшного, рад был помочь!